# putSerializable for Bundle OK but getSerializable depreciated (passing GregorianCalendar date)

Tags: android, kotlin

So I'm using the following code to put values into a Bundle

```
val arguments = Bundle()
arguments.putSerializable(DATE_PICKER_DATE, viewModel.getFilterDate())
dialogFragment.arguments = arguments
```

getFilterDate() returns a GregorianCalendar.time.

This seems fine but when I unpack the bundle with

```
val givenDate = arguments.getSerializable(DATE_PICKER_DATE) as Date
```

It says getSerializable is depreciated.

Can live with this for now but would rather not use depreciates stuff.

Did a load of googling and the simplest way to do this seem to be to use a long to pass the date in milliseconds, which will work for this but does mean some extra date processing but wondered if there is a better alternative to pass complex objects, such as GregorianCalendar dates?  Be good to have a nice generic solution.  Did look at Parcelables and found https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles but it was not much help.  Lacked example code that was useful to me.  My search has led me here.

PS

I think the way to put the Date into bundle is

```
arguments.putLong(DATE_PICKER_DATE, viewModel.getFilterDate().time)
```

And to get it back to a date is

```
val givenDate = Date(arguments.getLong(DATE_PICKER_DATE))
```

Which I guess is a good solution this time but wondering if there is a more generic solution like Serialise.

Comment: There is no better way to store a date than with a Long UTC timestamp. Also, any of the date related classes in `java.util` should be avoided in favor of the ones in `java.time`, which are more robust and easier to use correctly.

Comment: You mean store it in a bundle as a long (like my PS abovce).

Comment: I guess I was thinking in terms of longer term storage. If it's just for a Bundle which is only in use during the current session of your app, you don't have to worry about future-proofing, so probably it's fine to use Serializable if it saves you some code.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a deprecated warning, look at the warning to see if there's any information about *why* it's deprecated and what you're supposed to use instead - or [look at the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#getSerializable(java.lang.String)) for the method (usually the same thing):

> **This method was deprecated in API level 33.**
>
> Use the type-safer `getSerializable(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)` starting from Android `Build.VERSION_CODES#TIRAMISU`.

So basically, it's telling you to use a new `getSerializable` method instead, one where you explicitly provide the class of the object being deserialised. So if you're using the `Date` provided by `GregorianCalendar#getTime`, you'd do:

```
val givenDate = arguments.getSerializable(DATE_PICKER_DATE, Date::class.java)
```

Also note that this is an *API 33 (Tiramisu)* thing - that means it's not available on lower APIs (so you'd need to use the deprecated method for those, with an API check to work out which to use). It also means it's only just been deprecated, so it will stick around for a while yet - you have the option of just using it! It's your call, but it's unlikely to disappear for a few years.

The other option for this kind of thing is to use a *Compat* library that calls the relevant method depending on API, handling all the boilerplate for you. I can't see anything for this specific method (although I only checked `BundleCompat` to see if it was added) but maybe later - it's always worth a look for API-dependent methods though.